# Need help in highlighting the text in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have built a free text search engine in rails ,I want to highlight search word in result page where, each word in the phrase may not be adjacent to each other( that is they may be present in any part of the text content).
I have tried with highlight method of ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper as

```
<%= highlight(content.body, @search_keywords) -%>
```

(Where @search_keywords has the phrase)

But this is not high lighting a phrase. Can any one help me in this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does the html look like when that line is rendered?

Comment: If @search_keywords has 1 word then it will be highlighted if more than 1 word then no highlight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass array of words to `highlight` function. See [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/highlight).

```
<%= highlight(content.body, @search_keywords.split) -%>
```